# malloc() crashing on Windows but not on Mac

Tags: c, malloc

The following code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    FILE** f;
    if ( (*f = (FILE *)malloc( sizeof(FILE *)) ) == NULL) {
        printf("Out of RAM or some other disaster!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("OK!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

compiles and runs without complaint on Mac OS X 10.8.  However on Windows 7 (compiling with MinGW) it crashes on the malloc().  Why would this be and or any ideas to stop it happening?

Thanks!

Note: This was obviously originally part of a larger program but I've reduced the entire program to the above and tried just this code on both the Mac and PC and have replicated the behaviour.

Comment: "I've reduced the entire program to the above" - well done!

Comment: Actually, the code won't compile before you remove an opening parenthesis in the `if`. You close one less than you open there.

Comment: @DanielFischer d'oh, typo in the transcription; fixed now.

Answer (score 7):

`f` is not pointing anywhere yet, so dereferencing it (`*f`) is invalid and has an undefined behavior.

Comment: It's the same problem as `int *j; *j = 1;`.

Answer (score 4):

You're assigning the malloc-ed memory to *f which is undefined behavior, since f is uninitialized.
Change to

```
f = (FILE **)malloc( sizeof(FILE *))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to allocate `f` first

```
f = (FILE **)malloc( sizeof(FILE *))
```

and then you can allocate for `*f`

```
*f = (FILE *)malloc( sizeof(FILE))
```

Answer (score 1):

The general idiom for dynamic allocation is

```
T *p = malloc(sizeof *p * num_elements);
```

or

```
T *p;
...
p = malloc(sizeof *p * num_elements);
```

Thus, the proper way to allocate `f` is:

```
f = malloc(sizeof *f)
```

The cast is unnecessary in C, and casting the result of `malloc` is discouraged.  Since the type of the expression `*f` is `FILE *`, `sizeof *f` is the same as `sizeof (FILE *)`, except that with `sizeof *f` you don't need to worry about making sure you have the type right.